# String comparison in Java

Tags: java

I want to compare two strings using Java. First sting `name` i get from `.mif` file using GDAL in cp1251  encoding. Second `kadname` i get from jsp. To compare i do this:

```
if (attrValue instanceof String)
{
    String string3 = 
        new String((attrValue.toString()).getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "cp1251");
    dbFeature.setAttribute(name, string3);
    System.out.println("Name=" + name);
    System.out.println("kadname=" + kadname);
    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(kadname))
    {
        kadnum = string3;
        System.out.println("string3" + string3);
    }
}
```

And in console i get this:

```
Name = kadnumm
kadname = kadnumm
```

Whats wrong with this?

Comment: What's the question exactly? Are you asking why the Strings are not equal?

Comment: Yes. I'm interested why equals strins not equal.

Comment: And what is right for this question?

Comment: I guess it is because of trailing spaces or some non printable characters. To debug try putting the values in quotes like:
    System.out.println("Name='" + name+"'");
    System.out.println("kadname='" + kadname+"'");

Comment: can you let us know what you are setting in name and kadname. are u doing any encoding for that strings as well? also what ever you have put as the console output is not the original console output.

Comment: String walues u can find i question. Im encode `name` to cp1251. `kadname` get a encode from jsp utf8 i think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only reason I can see for them not being equal is the leading or trailing whitespace.

You can `trim` the string to remove any of those whitespaces, and then compare them: -

```
if (name.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(kadname.trim()))
```

Or, there might be some other `non-printable` characters, which won't get removed by `trimming`. You can try printing your strings in `single quotes`, and check whether there are any: -

```
System.out.println("'" + name + "'");
```

Comment: Wait a minute try to do this. Redeploy going so slow.

Comment: its realy help. And why did not I think to trim jsp response(. Thank you.

Comment: @KliverMax. Whenever you see some strange behaviour with your string comparison. Always try to trim your string to be sure that there is not leading or trailing whitespace. Because, Java cannot have wrong implementation of `equals`. :)